# Indentation renders code block instead of a simple link

Tags: markdown, jekyll

I use the Liquid templating system in a post, like this
`{% for post in site.tags.testing-stuff reversed %}`
  `{% if post.day != 0 %}`
    `[Day {{ post.day }} ({{ post.title }})]({{ post.url }})`
  `{% endif %}

{% endfor %}`

So the `for` lines has no spaces, the `if` lines have two spaces, and the link line has four spaces. the four spaces cause `jekyll`/`markdown` to make the link a code block instead.
How can I make this render properly?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use liquid templates inside a post. Write your post content using markdown or textile, and save it in the `_posts` directory of your Jekyll site.

Over in the `_layouts` folder you can create layouts that use liquid templates to do what you're trying to achieve here. Make sure your posts specify which layout to use in their YAML front matter, and you should be good to go.

Comment: cool. I'll try that. but what about a part of the post. say i need to have liquid templates in a post, should i make a separate layout?

Comment: @pvinis I'm not really sure why you'd want to do that, but yes you should use a layout.